# Jupyter Notebook displaying incorrect graphs

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create a square wave that increases in frequency over time but Jupiter does not know how to work with square signals from scipy or numpy. Spider does. Why is Jupyter dumb?

[image: Jupiter being bad]

[image: Spider showing the correct graph]

Comment: Could you please add your code and graphs instead of the link to a picture? It would be easier to replicate

Comment: In Jupyter you are using the np.square, which is the element-wise square of the input, and not the square-wave.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.linspace(0,1,100, endpoint=True)
plt.plot(t, signal.square(2* np.pi*5*t))
```

on Jupyter
[image: jupyter]
and Colab
[image: colab]
and seems ok.

Please, could you restart kernel and try again?
In case that it doesn't work, please, provide more information.

Comment: This works too in my `jupyter                   1.0.0                    py38_7`.

Comment: there's no other information I can give, I've tried everything up to and including restarting my computer. I guess Jupiter is not a good program. I'll just use spider then. But thanks for your time